# call a java program from a webapp in tomcat server - the java program is out side of tomcat server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications, jvm

I have a webapp in tomcat server.
also i have a java program outside the tomcat server - in linux machine root.
i need to call the java program outside and get a response to the webapp.
is this possible to do?

Please give me an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use exec method on runtime object:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process proc = rt.exec("whatever_you_want_to_run"); 
int exitVal = proc.exitValue();
```

Comment: Also, if you want to do multiple actions or want to call multiple programs, you can wrap it in Shell script and then call the shell script using above code.

Comment: @Garbage : thank you for the code. I'll try and see. thnx in advance.